# How to update a UDF in Redshift (amazon)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have created a UDF in Redshift. I can view this in the pg_proc table by

```
select * from pg_proc where proname ilike 'my_udf';
```

Now i need to update this function (**including the function signature**). I have tried using update statements on the pg_proc table with no luck.

**EDIT**: Seems the only way to update the signature is to delete the function although `DROP FUNCTION <function_name>` does not seems to work.

What is the correct way to do this? Also knowing the function signature would be helpful, is there any way to view that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] FUNCTION...` to redefine the User-Defined Function (UDF).

See: [CREATE FUNCTION - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html)

If the signature is changing, you might need to `DROP FUNCTION` and then `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: DROP FUNCTION <function_name> results in a syntax error. Am i missing something?

Comment: list of arguments with their data types just like in the create statement